# PHP parsing from print_r()

Tags: php

I'm working with some API integration and I have a limitation with understanding Objects.

Not my code, but here's what I have:

```
<?php
print_r(pingSample());
?>
```

The result on the browser is this:

**PingResponse Object ( [PingResult] => 1 )**

The function pingSample is not mine, it's from Docusign.

I want to just extract the "1", or if it's a bad result I'm sure it will return "0".
I'm not experienced with Object Oriented coding, yet.  So, I'm assuming this is a simple example, in an API setting.  But I'm not sure.

For those who want to laugh at my attempt:

```
$blah = pingSample();
echo $blah['PingResult'];
```

So far, nothing returns on the browser.  Apache logs return this: 
**PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type PingResponse as array**

How do I extract only the value of PingResult?

Comment: So...you're taking a data structure, passing it to a string via `print_r`, and then parsing the string to get part of the data structure back again?  **Why** would you do that when you can just call `pingSample()` and get the value that you need?  Since `pingSample()` is an object, I believe you can do `echo pingSample()->PingResult;`

Comment: @Jack, I would encourage you to post an answer next time. However, I would discourage such code in the event you needed the object for additional use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$blah = pingSample();
echo $blah->PingResult;
```

Comment: yep, that was it.  hurray for OO.

Answer (score 4):

Object properties are accessed by using the pointer (*arrow*) notation, not array (bracket) notation.

```
$blah = pingSample();
echo $blah->PingResult;
```

Read more on [Classes and Objects in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo $blah->PingResult;
```